# How to change key in python dictionary

Tags: python

How to change key in python dictionary:
for example:

```
data={'998905653388.0':('1254', '1255', 'Hello world'), =>
      '998905653388':('1254', '1255', 'Hello world')}
```

I tried like this:

```
for key in data.keys():
    new_key=key.split('.')
    data[key] = data[new_key[0]]
    data.pop(key, None)
```

But it throws an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Or you can suggest other options.
Thank you.

Comment: `'998905653388.0'.split('.')` isn't `'998905653388'`.

Comment: Your data assignment is the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate trought the `list` of your `keys` so it create a copy of them and once you modify keys inside your dict, it won't conflict.

For each iteration you create a new `key:val` in your dict and `pop` out the old `key`

```
for key in list(data.keys()): data[key.split('.')[0]] = data.pop(key)
```

Comment: for key in list(data.keys()): 
    data[new_key] = data.pop(key.split('.')[0])
KeyError: '998905653388'

Comment: Yeah i've edited my code, it had a wrong syntax

Comment: No need to create a temporary list just for iteration. `for key in data:` is enough.

Comment: That was my first thought by when I do so, I get that : `RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration`. My dict is being modified while i'm iterating throught it, I need some kind of copy, that's what the list is for.

Answer (score 1):

Lists cannot be dictionary keys.

`str.split` returns a list. I think you mean `key.split('.')[0]` - which will give a string.

```py
for key in list(data.keys()):
    new_key = key.split('.')[0]
    data[new_key] = data[key]
    data.pop(key, None)
```

Comment: tried like this
but now another error:
KeyError: "998905653388"

Comment: Try now - `key` and `new_key` were the wrong way round

Comment: you need to wrap the _keys_ with a list/tuple or you will get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: What do you mean by "Wrap the keys"?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way with [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) method.

```
for key in list(data):
    data[key.partition('.')[0]] = data.pop(key)
```